# How to change palette of plot, particularly how to make it grey scale?

Tags: python, plotly

Here is my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 1',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[3, 6, 4],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[1, 0.5, 1.5]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 2',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[4, 7, 3],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[0.5, 1, 2]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

output:

[image]

**Question:** How to make that plot grey scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@rpanai's example is a global setting, but if you want to set it individually, you can do so with the following content.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

# colors = ['darkgray',lightslategray','slategray']*2
colors = ['rgb(37,37,37)','rgb(87,87,87)','rgb(150,150,150)']*2

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 1',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[3, 6, 4],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[1, 0.5, 1.5]),
    width=0.15,
    marker_color=colors
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 2',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[4, 7, 3],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[0.5, 1, 2]),
    width=0.15,
    marker_color=colors
))
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How to change it so that all first bars from all groups have one color and all second bars from all groups different color?

Comment: There may be a better way to do it, but 'colorsA' for Group A and 'colorsB' for Group B. 'colorB' would be enough to set it to 'colorB'.

Answer (score 0):

Here I suggest you to have a look at [colorscales](https://plotly.com/python/builtin-colorscales/). You can use one of them or create a custom one.

## `plotly.graph_objects`

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

# Here I picked this but you can build your own palette
colors = px.colors.sequential.Greys

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 1',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[3, 6, 4],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[1, 0.5, 1.5]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 2',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[4, 7, 3],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[0.5, 1, 2]),
    width=0.15
))

# pick one color per group
for i, data in enumerate(fig.data):
    data["marker"] ={"color": colors[i%len(colors)]}
    
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

[image]

## `plotly.express`

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3','Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'],
                   "y":[3, 6, 4, 4, 7, 3],
                   "error":[1, 0.5, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 2],
                   "group":["Group 1"] * 3 + ["Group 2"] * 3})

fig = px.bar(df, 
             x="x", 
             y="y", 
             color="group", 
             barmode='group', 
             error_y="error", 
             color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Greys)

# you can't define bar width within px
# so we set on every trace
for data in fig.data:
    data["width"] = 0.15

fig.show()
```